# Delete row from localStorage in Datatables after ordering

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatables

I'm testing Datatables plugin and need some advice. My problem is that I can't delete a specific row in my table after ordering. For removing rows I use .index() method. Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hvntqgm3/2/)

At first I find closest row:

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr');
```

then using this code to set index number:

```
var index = $("#example tbody").children().index(row);
```

And of course after ordering this index number changes. 
Can you suggest something more efficient?

Comment: Always use some form of primary key value to identify a specific row. Never depend on the display order.

Comment: Search by some other unique key, not by element index..

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie thanks, but I am not using ant data bases.

Comment: A primary key does not have to mean database... Call it a unique ID, call it whatever you like, only use one :)

Comment: @RayonDabre for example what unique key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering name as unique entry:

```
var name = $(row).find('td:first').text();
for (var i = 0; i < dataSort.length; i++) {
  if (dataSort[i][0] == name) {
    break;
  }
}
dataSort.splice(i, 1);
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/hvntqgm3/3/)

Comment: Yes! this is really great and simple... Thank you

Comment: ye! I tried, but I have low reputation yet. http://take.ms/e0rzr I will do it in future

Answer (score 0):

this may be the code u needed...

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr'); 
       var nRow = row[0];
       dataTable.dataTable().fnDeleteRow(nRow);
```

Comment: sorry, but could you be more specific? Where I should put it and how it will work? If it is possible, please, update my fiddle